# Find Links To A Page

Tags: asp-classic

I'm looking for a tool that I can point to a website and it can tell me what pages are all pointing to a specific page, for example: What pages are pointing to AboutUs.asp etc. The website is online and just way to big to download to my local machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> http://google.com/search?q=link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions

If you only want internal links:

> http://google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags